# condition statement doesn't work

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

i'm trying to do a simple condition check like:

```
$test = 1;
$test_ = $test==-1?"Test--1":$test==1?"Test-1":$test==0?"Test-0":"Test";
echo $test_;
```

The output is `Test-0` but must be `Test-1`.

Which could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you stack ternary operators into each other. Don't do that...it's ugly and a maintenance hell.

Comment: The problem is that you're nesting ternaries without paying heed to the warnings about doing that in the PHP documentation.... `if`/`else` is more readable, and intuitive

Comment: If I have to do exactly what you did, I would have done this `echo $test_ = "Test-" . $test;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : Put brackets for conditions.

```
$test = 1;
$test_ = ($test==-1)?"Test--1":($test==1?"Test-1":($test==0?"Test-0":"Test"));
echo $test_;
```

output :

```
Test-1
```

Comment: Brackets are so useful for ternary operations :)

Comment: Ok, it works! :) thanks.. but why it works with brackets and it doesn't work without?

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$test_ = $test==-1?"Test--1":$test==1?"Test-1":$test==0?"Test-0":"Test";
```

to

```
$test_ = $test==-1?"Test--1":($test==1?"Test-1":($test==0?"Test-0":"Test"));
```

working example http://viper-7.com/msuCyk

```
// output Test-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator in PHP is left to right, therefore, its executed like this:

```
$test_ = (( ( $test==-1 ? "Test--1" :$test==1) ? "Test-1":$test==0)?"Test-0":"Test");
```